# What is the difference between ipa created by archive and export and the one created by dragging .app file into iTunes?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcarchive

What is the difference between ups created by using archive of xcode and ipa created by dragging .app file to iTunes? If there is no difference then why sign in required to export ipa from organizer and not to drag it iTunes?

Comment: now have no option for app in ituns so you not allow to dragging.

Comment: but still you can zip .app file and save it as .ipa